# Delete rows whose mean is less than a certain value - R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, rows

I am trying to drop all rows of a dataframe with a mean value < 1. I can do this by first creating a column with mean values, and then dropping based on that column value, however I am looking for a cleaner way to do this without editing the data frame itself.

ex df:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| y | 0 | 1 | 0.5 | 1 |
| z | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

desired results:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| z | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate average of each row using  `rowMeans` and drop the row whose average is less than 1.

```
df[rowMeans(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE) > 1,]

#  A B C D E
#1 x 1 3 2 1
```

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(rowMeans(select(., where(is.numeric))) > 1)
```

Comment: The first one initially resulted in an error however I changed if to `df[rowMeans(df[,-1,drop=F], na.rm = TRUE) > 1,]` and it worked great. All the other solutions also resulted in errors, but I am guessing that has to do with how my df is formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df[apply(df[-1],1,function(x) mean(x) > 1),]
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  A         B     C     D     E
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 x         1     3     2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(df, rowMeans(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE) > 1)
```